# Is this a correct way of accessing mysql in class fashion or OOP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
class DBAcess{
    private $_mysql_connection;
    function db_access(){
        $this->_mysql_connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'aaaaa', 'test') or die('cant connect to the db server');
    }
    function display_user($user_id){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM email WHERE id = '$user_id'";
        $db_handle = mysqli_query($this->_mysql_connection, $sql) or die('cant query db');
        $num_count = mysqli_num_rows($db_handle);
        if($num_count != 1){
            echo 'no record';
        }else{
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db_handle)){
            echo $row['email'];
        }       
        }

    }

}


    $db_operation = new DBAcess();
    $db_operation->db_access();
    $db_operation->display_user(1);
```

Comment: I think the answer to your actual question is NO

Comment: You may use open source modules that already does that eg https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends. If you're asking whether or not this is good practice: it will work, but there are issues with this code that will make it difficult to maintain.
You database class should only deal with connections, running queries, getting inserted ids, as well as helper methods, like formatting the results of those queries, etc.
Your user class should call database class to run queries and obtain user info.
You might also want to consider moving database credentials into config file. Declare them as constants, so you can just use _DB_SERVER_, _DB_USER_ and so on.

Comment: cant give link resource to learn how to make your code maintainable?

Comment: Any popular open source PHP project will do, just study the code, try to understand how and why they chose to write code like that and not like that. This will give you so much more than any tutorial, because this will be coming from a real life project, that solves real problems.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I try to model my classes after the tables in the database and use a separate database class to do the heavy lifting. Sometimes I do it statically if the DB class is only doing on-demand queries, not caring if the handle is saved, other times I instantiate a DB class to run multiple queries. Example below is using statically calling DB to save code, but Im sure you will be able to do it as it fits your application.

I also strongly encourage you to use the PDO-library to handle your database-stuff. Mostly you can use the same code with all drivers, though some exceptions in behaviour do exist. It also eliminates any need to be careful with input from database or the web if you prepare the queries as shown. SQL-injections is thus a non-issue.

I haven't tried running this, but the big picture is there at least

```
<?php

class User {
    // Don't know your fields, these are examples
    private $first_name;
    private $last_name;
    private $email;
    private $id;

    public function __construct($user_id = NULL){
        if( !empty($user_id) ){
            $this->loadFromDB($user_id);
        }
    }

    public function loadFromDB($id){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM email WHERE id = :id';

        $result = Database::query($sql,[':id'=>$id]);
        if( sizeof($result) !== 1){
            throw new Exception("Failed to load user or user not found");
        }

        $this->first_name = $result[0]["first_name"];
        $this->last_name = $result[0]["lastname"];
        $this->email = $result[0]["email"];
        $this->id = $id;


    }

    public function display(){
        echo $this->email;
    }
}

class Database {

    public static function query($sql, $params){
        try{
            $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1;charset=UTF8','root','aaaa');
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        return $result;
    }
}

$user = new User(1);
$user->display();
```